# How to work out why Eclipse is slow to start JVM?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

In the last week or two, when I run Java code inside Eclipse Juno, it takes 2-3 seconds before it starts executing. I know it doesn't sound like long, but it adds up to being really annoying. (The same thing happens when I run JUnit tests).

It didn't use to take this long. It used to be almost instantaneous. I can't figure out what has changed in my system configuration and how to change it back.

In terms of the environment, the only thing that I can think of is that I recently installed a Java plugin into Chrome, but I can't see how that would affect Eclipse, as it's using a different JDK (and not the JRE I installed).

What should my next step be? How can I narrow-down what's causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet this is because of having so many projects that are open in the workspace! You can close any non-used project by right-clicking on it and then select <kbd>Close Project</kbd>.